# Fibonacci Sequence and changing the rule

Tags: r, fibonacci

I wrote a loop to compute the first 10 numbers of the Fibonacci sequence. F(0)=0 ; F(1)=1 ; Rule: F(i)=F(i-2)+F(i-1)

```
x <- c(0,1)
while (length(x) < 10) {
  position <- length(x)
  new <- x[position] + x[position-1]
  x <- c(x,new)
}
print(x)
```

Now I wanted to change the rule to: F(i)=F(i-1)-F(i-2)

```
x <- c(0,1)
while (length(x) < 10) {
  position <- length(x)
  new <- x[position-1] - x[position]
  x <- c(x,new)
}
print(x)
```

But the (small) change in the code doesn´t deliver the correct sequence. 
Is there a smarter way to this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the rule to be `F(i)=F(i-1)-F(i-2)`, then it should be

```
new <- x[position] - x[position-1]
```

On another note, if you are going to do this for just a small size vector then it makes no difference, but if you plan to go for a larger number then you should allocate the memory for the object beforehand, with a vector of NAs, Os or whatever you prefer. Otherwise, if you make your vector grow with each iteration, your code could become really slow.

Something like this:

```
len <- 10
x <- rep(NA, len)
x[1] <- 0
x[2] <- 1
for (i in 3:len) {
  x[i] <- x[i-1] - x[i-2]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do a full parametric function:

```
 fibonacci <- function(len, x,func){

      while (length(x) < len) {
        position <- length(x)
        new <- func(x,position)
        x <- c(x,new)
      }
      x
    }

    fibo1 <- function(x,position){x[position] + x[position-1]}
    fibo2 <- function(x,position){x[position] - x[position-1]}
    fibo3 <- function(x,position){x[position-1] - x[position]}
    start <- c(0,1)
    fibonacci(10,start,fibo1)
    fibonacci(10,start,fibo2)
    fibonacci(10,start,fibo3)
```

Or using @mgiormenti best code:

```
fibonacci <- function(len, x,func){

        for (i in (length(x)+1):len) {
          x[i] <- func(x,i-1)
        }

    x
}

fibo1 <- function(x,position){x[position] + x[position-1]}
fibo2 <- function(x,position){x[position] - x[position-1]}
fibo3 <- function(x,position){x[position-1] - x[position]}
start <- c(0,1)
fibonacci(10,start,fibo1)
fibonacci(10,start,fibo2)
fibonacci(10,start,fibo3)
```